# XML snippet with substitution crashing sublime text 3

Tags: xml, regex, code-snippets, sublimetext3, substitution

I'm trying to write a sublime xml snippet but I have two problems.

First the completions aren't showing up for xml files so the only way I can activate the snippet is with `cmd-shift-p`. They work in other file types so not sure why this is.

More importantly though I'm using regex in the snippet to force input text to uppercase which I can get to work in the following scenario:

```
<content><![CDATA[
    lower: $1 and upper: ${1/(.*)/\U\1/}
]]></content>
```

but if I try to do it with uppercase only:

```
<content><![CDATA[
    upper only: ${1/(.*)/\U\1/}
]]></content>
```

ST3 crashes.

I assume you need to have text to replace and thats why it crashes but is there another way to do this?

Also I'm assuming this is a bug and sublime should throw an error instead of shutting down... (I have seen a bug report somewhere for this)

Answer (score 1):

In default settings, the completion pop-up is not available for the `text` scope. You can add the scope (or only `text.xml`) to `auto_complete_selector` in your user settings.

About your main problem, I'd probably report this as a bug on the Sublime Text [forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=1).